# How to save suggester index

Tags: java, solr, spell-checking

I'm using an AnalyzingInfixSuggester in my Solr app like this:

```xml
<searchComponent class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" name="suggest">
    <lst name="spellchecker">
        <str name="name">suggest</str>
        <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
        <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.fst.AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
        <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">suggestAnalyzer</str>
        <str name="field">Suggestions</str>
        <str name="fieldType">string</str>
        <str name="storeDir">dict_ac</str>
        <float name="threshold">0.005</float>
        <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
    </lst>
</searchComponent>
```

The storeDir parameter tells it where to store a disk copy of the suggest index so it doesn't have to rebuild the in memory index every time the application starts.  The "dict_ac" directory is created with an empty file inside called iwfsta.bin.

I'm running Solr on Tomcat through eclipse, and this is the log message:

> "SEVERE: Store Lookup build from index on field: Suggestions failed reader has: 100 docs"

The in-memory suggester index is working fine in the application.  I've tried giving RW permissions to all on this file, but that didn't solve it.

The questions are

1. What is wrong with my setup?
2. How would I debug such a problem?

EDIT: Inside my eclipse install dir (not workspace), it is creating a folder called analyzingInfixSuggesterDir, which contains several files comprising a Lucene index.

Comment: I prefer to give a try to standard Jetty, that came with Solr. I never have a permission issue problem with jetty.

Comment: I also don't think it's a permissions issue.  I allowed everyone to have RW permissions on the file, which didn't solve the problem.